# Binary number function

Tags: c++, binary

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void binary(unsigned  a) {
    int i;
    cout << "0" << endl;
    do {
        for (i = 1; i < a; i=i/2) {
            if ((a & i) != 0) {
                cout << "1" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "0" << endl;
            
            }
    
        }
    }
    while (1 <= a && a <= 10);
}

int main(void) {
    binary(4);
    cout << endl;
}
```

I wrote a code about binary numbers. İt should give bits respect to entering number like for
4 (0100) for 2 (10). However my code goes infinity could you explain. I wrote in visual
studio and I cannot use <bits/stdc++.h> because there is no such a library in visual studio

Comment: ***I wrote in visual studio and I cannot use <bits/stdc++.h> because there is no such a library in visual studio*** That is a very good thing. Never use this header ever. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: Ask yourself: If `a` is `4`, when does `while (1 <= a && a <= 10)` end?

Comment: @NathanOliver it can change I just wrote . İt should be in function and our teacher can give another number too but according to constraints it should be between 1 and 10

Comment: *because there is no such a library in visual studio* -- Hurray for Visual Studio. -- *and our teacher* -- Your teacher is giving you `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?  I hope not.

Comment: You should search the internet for "c++ binary number cout" or something similar.  There are a lot of similar questions on both StackOverflow and the internet.

Comment: In your loop, `i` has an initial value of `1` (actually `1u`) and the loop keeps dividing `i` by `2` (via `i = i/2`).    Dividing `1` by `2` produces `0` (rounding toward zero).   Dividing `0` by `2`  also produces `0`.   So the only possible values of `i` in that loop are `1` and `0`.   If `a` has a value of `4`,  the test `i < a` will always be true.   Hence an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Initially `i` is 1 but `i = i / 2` sets `i` to 0, where it remains. The inner loop, therfore, loops for ever.

To output an `unsigned` number `a` in binary, use

```
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(a) * CHAR_BIT>(a) << '\n';
```

(There is, at the time of writing no `std::bin` i/o manipulator cf. `std::hex`.)

Comment: `sizeof(a)` -- Wouldn't you need to multiply by the number of bits in a byte?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Oops.

Comment: thank you very much but our teacher said you can not use built in function.

Comment: @SudeŞahin *but our teacher said you can not use built in function* -- Please post up-front what you can or cannot use.  Otherwise you have persons wasting time putting up legitimate answers that will not be accepted (at least won't get the green tick mark).

Comment: We'll you're using `std::cout`?

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you but I have already wrote using namespace std . So, I do not need std::cout I can write just cout

Comment: Indeed, and no professional uses `using namespace std;` as it causes namespace pollution for one thing. You're still obviously using `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

Without using a built-in function, you can write your own function and perform your operation as follows.

### Solution-1

```
#include <iostream>
void binary(unsigned int number)
{
    if (number / 2 != 0) {
        binary(number / 2);
    }
    std::cout << number % 2;
}

int main() {
    binary(10);
}
```

### Solution-2

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

void binary(unsigned int number)
{
    std::string str = "";
    while (number != 0) { 
        str = (number % 2 == 0 ? "0" : "1") + str;
        number /= 2; 
    }
    std::cout << str;
}
int main()
{
   binary(4);
}
```

**Note :** Don't use `using namespace std;` . [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)